# Property of bounded sequences in $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am a bit embarassed about this question, but I’ll go ahead anyway.

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded space and consider the Sobolev space $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ endowed with its usual norm $\|\cdot\|$. Let $(u_n)_n\subset  W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ be a sequence such that
$$(\| u_n\|)_n \leq \beta,$$
for a positive constant $\beta$ which does not depend on $n$.

My question is: for $\alpha>\beta$, we can say that $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ exists such that
$$\| u_n\| \leq\alpha\quad\mbox{ for all } n\geq n_0?$$

I am sorry for my probably stupid question, but I hope someone could help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does the notation $(\|u_{n}\|)_{n} \leq \beta$ mean?  Does it mean $\|u_{n}\| \leq \beta$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$?  If so, the inequality $\beta < \alpha$ is all you need.

Comment: @PeterMorfe, it means exactly what you said. So my guess is true?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. If $||u_n||\leq \beta<\alpha$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then of course it holds for some $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$. Choose any $n_0$ you like in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course: if $\|u_n\|\leq \beta$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha>\beta,$ then $$\|u_n\|\leq \beta<\alpha$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, it is true for any $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$.

Saying $(\|u_n\|)_n\leq\beta$ is the same thing as saying $\|u_n\|\leq\beta$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$